# Xcode fails to import module every second time when running tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Every second time I try to run tests in my project, Xcode **11.6** fails to load a module.
All I get is a generic SIGABRT Error with a message:

```
error: module importing failed: invalid pathname
dyld: could not load inserted library '<path>/Frameworks/libXCTestBundleInject.dylib' because image not found
```

This wouldn't bother me so much if it wasn't for the fact that the crash happens **exactly** every second time.

Did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: Can you check this apple forum link https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126836? if your issue is with iOS 11 also check https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9165#issuecomment-550273696.